# Performing an action as python script closes

Tags: python

I was wondering if it was possible to perform an action at any given point in  a basic python script, so say when it is close. I have the following code to find prime numbers (Just for fun)

```
number = 1
primelist = []
nonprime = []

while number < 1000:

    number += 1

    for i in range(number):
        if i != 1 and i != number and i !=0:
            if number%i == 0:
                nonprime.append(number)
            else:
                primelist.append(number)

nonprimes = open("nonprimes.txt", "w")

for nonprime in set(primelist) & set(nonprime):
    nonprimes.write(str(nonprime) + ", ")

nonprimes.close()
```

So basically i wanted to run the last part as the script is stopped. If this isn't possible is there a way where say i press "space" while the program is running and then it saves the list?

Cheers in advance :)

EDIT:

I've modified the code to include the atexit module as suggested, but it doesn't appear to be working. Here it is:

import time, atexit

```
class primes():



    def __init__(self):

        self.work(1)

    def work(self, number):

        number = 1
        self.primelist = []
        self.nonprime = []

        while number < 20:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print "Done"

            number += 1

            for i in range(number):
                if i != 1 and i != number and i !=0:
                    if number%i == 0:
                        self.nonprime.append(number)
                    else:
                        self.primelist.append(number)

        nonprimes = open("nonprimes.txt", "w")

        for nonprime in set(self.primelist) & set(self.nonprime):
            nonprimes.write(str(nonprime) + ", ")

        nonprimes.close()


    def exiting(self, primelist, nonprimelist):
        primelist = self.primelist
        nonprimelist = self.nonprime

        nonprimes = open("nonprimes.txt", "w")

        for nonprime in set(self.primelist) & set(self.nonprime):
            nonprimes.write(str(nonprime) + ", ")

        nonprimes.close()

atexit.register(exiting)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    primes()
```

Comment: what do you mean by last part?

Comment: The part where it saves the list to a .txt file , sorry for not specifying

Comment: What you are looking for is called multithreading. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: There is an indentation issue now in your code.

Comment: Not for me :/ just doesn't save the list

Comment: Your script takes a while to run. So do you want to stop it at any time (before it has reached 1000) and still save the results saved so far?

Comment: You are aware that there are faster ways to calculate a list of primes?

Comment: mhm I am aware that there is allot faster ways, I just wanted to kind of try it, and kinda sat down and just typed it. :) Wasn't really thinking of speed until i realized what the actual highest prime number actually is :c

Answer (score 0):

While I'm pretty certain the file object does cleanup and flushes the stuff to file when it is reclaimed. The best way to go about this is to use a with statement.

```
with open("nonprimes.txt", "w") as nonprimes:
    for nonprime in set(primelist) & set(nonprime):
        nonprimes.write(str(nonprime) + ", ")
```

The boiler plate code of closing the file and such is performed automatically when the statement ends.

Answer (score 0):

Python has an atexit module that allows you to register code you want executed when a script exits:

```
import atexit, sys

def doSomethingAtExit():
    print "Doing something on exit"

atexit.register(doSomethingAtExit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(1)
    print "This won't get called"
```

Comment: hmm, I've modified my code using the atexit module and for some reason it doesn't appear to be working. The modified code is in the question

Comment: You have an indentation problem with your exiting method. Also, it should be `if __name__`, not `while __name__`. And finally, it's probably best to move the contents of your `__init__` method into its own method. `__init__` is really just for instantiating a class, not doing actual work.

Comment: Ok i've edited the code again. Still don't get the list to save upon exit.

Comment: Still more problems with your code. (1) You're missing imports for the atexit and time modules. (2) The primelist and nonprimelist variables in existing aren't used in the method. (3) You're passing the exiting function to register(), when you should be passing a method. In other words, you should have `primesInstance = primes(); atexit.register(primesInstance.exiting)` and (4) You're still doing work in `__init__`. You should be doing something like `primesInstance = primes(); primesInstance.work(1)` instead.